# How do I make Firefox in Lubuntu use less virtual memory?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, ssd, ram, memory-usage

I have Lubuntu 14.04 installed on an old XP desktop, which has an Intel Celeron 2.00GHz and a SiS 651 graphics chipset. I have upgraded it with as much memory as it will take (2GB DDR), and a 120GB SSD.

Because of the SSD, I want to reduce disk caching. So I have configured Firefox using the about:config settings: setting browser.cache.disk.enable to false, browser.cache.disk.capacity to 0, and browser.cache.memory.capacity to 1500000. I have also changed the virtual memory swappiness using the "vm.swappiness=5" line in the /etc/sysctl.conf file (and re-booted). If I "cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness" I get 5.

However, when I start Firefox and the Task Manager, I can see that the "RSS" for Firefox is 141.1MB, but the VM-Size is 686.6MB. So Firefox is still writing to the SSD, but by virtual swap memory instead of by disk caching.

The Task Manager says that total memory used is 259MB of 1984MB. So it's not like the computer is low on memory.

How can I get Firefox to use more physical memory and less virtual memory?

Comment: Might be obvious, but did you reboot after changing swappiness? Maybe try using 1 instead of 5? If you don't need swap, you could always turn it off with sudo swapoff

Comment: @DKBose Updated!

Comment: @SuperSluether Yes I did reboot. I have played about with swappiness and have decided on 0. I am a little confused thinking about it: does VM-Size in Task Manager actually mean virtual memory used? When I type the command "free -m" I get the following `jeff@iqondesktop:~$ free -m  
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:          1984        839       1144          8         38        349  
-/+ buffers/cache:        451       1533  
Swap:            0          0          0`  
That suggest swap is not actually being used at the moment.

Comment: @DKBose `browser.cache.memory.enable` is already set to true (apparently by default in the "Status" column) on my computer's Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that VM-Size is nothing to worry about. From what I can gather from googling, VM-Size is not swap file usage. It appears to be the amount of memory that a process could use, whether physical or virtual, but the memory is not yet required. Therefore the memory could be neither physical nor swap memory to begin with, if it isn't being used then it doesn't matter.

I have noticed that the VM-Size for firefox will expand only to the value of my `browser.cache.memory.capacity` setting within firefox.

When I set the swappiness to 0 in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file (and reboot), then I check on the swap file using the command `free -m` while using firefox, I can see that the swap file is not in use. Therefore I can only conclude that the SSD is not being used to provide virtual swap memory while using firefox.