# Way to high virtual memory usage

Tags: 22.04, ram, memory-usage

So, I recently notices that on Ubuntu, programs are using way too much virtual memory.
[system monitor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMeFg.png)

How is MS Edge even using 1.2 TERA BYTES?? of Virtual Memory.

I've 16 GB physical memory and a 1TB NVMe SSD.

They're using virtual memory way above my system's capabilities.
Is it a bug or something? How can I fix it?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Windows 11 Dual booted.

Comment: Is this causing a problem?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/697400/how-do-i-make-firefox-in-lubuntu-use-less-virtual-memory  BTW, on my system (23.10) `msedge` is using exactly the same "Virtual Memory" (=1.2TB) as in yours.